# How to print errors from git-hooks to Android Studio Event Log?

Tags: git, android-studio, githooks

I have git-hook:

**pre-commit**

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar ktlint --color "/\**/src/**/*.kt"
if [[ $? -gt 0 ]]; then
  echo -e "\033[0;31mKotlin Code style violation. Please check errors above!\033[0m\n"
  echo -e "Hint: use \"./ktlint  -F <file pattern>\" for autocorrection.\n"
  exit 1
fi
```

When I use terminal command:

`>git commit -m "Any message"`

Output is in terminal , and it's ok for me:
[image]

But when I use `Android Studio` -> `VCS` -> `Commit...` <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>
Output is in `Event Log`, and it's not understandable:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
KOTLIN_LINTER_FILE=ktlint
TEMP_DIRECTORY=.temp
git diff --name-only --cached --relative | grep '.*kt$' | xargs ${TEMP_DIRECTORY}\\${KOTLIN_LINTER_FILE} --relative .
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then exit 1; fi
```

Comment: Where this script should be placed?

Comment: and also, what is the exact nature of the fix? Is it condition for returning exit code 1?